# How do I force my local master to push w/out conflict worry to the origin/master?

Tags: git

I managed to merge my local branch into my local master.
I want to push it to the server....but am encountering conflict.
How do I override... and force a sync with my local?

Comment: Maybe add your full git error message.

Comment: Do you want to overwrite remote branch?

Comment: Please clarify. What error message are you getting? The answer to your question depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

This will force a push:

```
git push -f origin master
```

Be careful, though. This will overwrite the master branch on origin.

Comment: Force pushing willy-nilly is never a good strategy. You should wait until the OP clarifies the question before posting such an answer.

Comment: The OP specifically asks how to force sync, and -f does that.

Answer (score -1):

```
git pull origin master
git push origin master
```

There's a good chance you're missing changes from `origin/master`.

Comment: No offense, but this is avery partial answer at best. Pulling and then pushing is no silver bullet.

Comment: No offense, but it sounds like the OP is extremely new to git and doesn't know about pulling or merging.